# How to compare two dates in MySql exluding the weekends(SAT,SUN)

Tags: mysql, sql-date-functions

I want to find the difference between two dates(dateStart, dateEnd) only for weekdays that are Mon - Fri in MySql query.

Here is my query which compares two dates and gives result if a week or more has passed:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME
WHERE status = 'Updated'
           AND
DATE_ADD(dateModified, INTERVAL 1 WEEK) >= NOW();
```

Comment: It isn't clear to me what you are asking here.  I don't see you actually comparing weekdays anywhere.  Please update with sample data and the expected output.

Comment: Comparing weekdays is my question @TimBiegeleisen . But I found out the solution my creating a function.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE_NAME
WHERE status = 'Updated'
  AND DATE_FORMAT(dateModified, '%w') IN (0, 6)
  AND DATE_ADD(dateModified, INTERVAL 1 WEEK) >= NOW();
```

Please refer to 
[Official MySQL documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

Create a Function as follows:

```
 CREATE FUNCTION TOTAL_WEEKDAYS(date1 DATE, date2 DATE)
  RETURNS INT
  RETURN ABS(DATEDIFF(date2, date1)) + 1
 - ABS(DATEDIFF(ADDDATE(date2, INTERVAL 1 - DAYOFWEEK(date2) DAY),
                ADDDATE(date1, INTERVAL 1 - DAYOFWEEK(date1) DAY))) / 7 * 2
 - (DAYOFWEEK(IF(date1 < date2, date1, date2)) = 1)
 - (DAYOFWEEK(IF(date1 > date2, date1, date2)) = 7);
```

Then query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE status = 'Updated'
                     AND 
 TOTAL_WEEKDAYS(dateModified, NOW()) >=7;
```

Works like a charm!